# How to refactor this factory method?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I have the following factory method which simply returns the proper IDatabase implementation. I'd like to refactor this over to my SimpleInjector container, but unsure how.

```
    public class DALFactory
    {
        public static IDatabase GetDAL()
        {
            string asm = "SQL"; /* Hardcoded choice of DAL */
            if (asm == "XML")
                return new XmlDatabase();
            if (asm == "SQL")
                return new SqlDatabase();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

I've tried understanding how I can register a collection, but how should I tell SimpleInjector which one to use when asking for an instance of IDatabase in my program? Open to any ideas. Just a theoretical program I'm trying to refactor for practice. Using DI (IoC) for the first time it's been such a pleasant, eye opening experience so far!

I've tried doing this, am I close?

```
Container.RegisterCollection<IDatabase>(new [] { typeof(SqlDatabase), typeof(XmlDatabase)});
Container.Register<IDatabase, XmlDatabase>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
Container.Register<IDatabase, SqlDatabase>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case the `asm` value is either hard-coded, or based on a value in the configuration file, you are basically saying that a running application only has one specific version of `IDatabase`.

This means that you should register as such:

```
string asm = "SQL"; /* Hardcoded choice of DAL */
if (asm == "XML")
    container.Register<IDatabase, XmlDatabase>();
if (asm == "SQL")
    container.Register<IDatabase, SqlDatabase>();
```

Comment: Sorry I'm such a newbie. I'm registering a bunch of stuff in my container class, but forgot to recognize I'm actually in a C# class and am not limited to only my Container-libraries methods, I can just put in my own logic as well. The answer is so simple, I feel so dumb now. Thank you!!!

Comment: If I wanted to make it more testable, instead of this ugly hard-coding, what alternative solution could you recommend? So IDatabase could be a mock implementation as well. Just add a third option to my hardcoded if loop, or is there a better approach?

Comment: @Amivit Ehen it comes to unit testing, the answer is completely different. For unit testing, you don't use a Container **at all**. You build up the class to test by hand.